# Is it possible to avoid or minimize the use of scheduling policies in operating system design?

Tags: resources, operating-system, scheduling

I recently stumbled upon the question above but I am not sure if I understand what it is asking.

How would one avoid the use of scheduling policies?

I would think that there isn't any other way...

Comment: I do neither. What does scheduling have to do with resource allocation?

Answer (score 1):

Scheduling policy has nothing to do with the resource allocation! Processes are scheduled basically, and hence allocated resources as such.

From ["Resource allocation (computer)" description on Wikipedia :-](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_allocation_(computer))

> When the user opens any program this will be counted as a process, and
>   therefore requires the computer to allocate certain resources for it
>   to be able to run. Such resources could have access to a section of
>   the computer's memory, data in a device interface buffer, one or more
>   files, or the required amount of processing power.

I don't know how you got confused between them. All the process would, at a time or another, get scheduled at any point of time; unless the CPU is an unfair one.

**EDIT :**

> How would one avoid the use of scheduling policies?

If there are more than one user-process to be executed, then one has to apply the scheduling policy so that the processes get executed in some order. There has to be a queue to hold all the processes. See a different case in BareMetal OS below.

Then, there is [BareMetal OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BareMetal) which is single address space OS.

> Multitasking on BareMetal is unusual for operating systems in this day
>   and age. BareMetal uses an internal work queue that all CPU cores
>   poll. A task added to the work queue will be processed by any
>   available CPU core in the system and will execute until completion,
>   which results in no context switch overhead.

So, BareMetal OS doesn't use any scheduling policy, it is based on polling of the work-queue by the cores.

Comment: I edited my question.
I had wrongly assumed the resources part.
The question is simply: "Is there any other way to design an operating system without the need of scheduling policies?"

Comment: @Sektrax - Edited my answer, if this helps, please feel free to accept and upvote the answer. Cheers.:)